# jquery form.validate conditional required

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to get a form to validate based on information that was submitted. Everything works fine if I make all fields required but my validation does not work as soon as I put in an if statement on the requirement.

Does not work:

```
var form = $( "#send_request_sms" );
    form.validate({
       rules: {
           first_name: { 
             required: true 
           } , 
               last_name: { 
               required: true 
           },              
                        mobile: { 
               required: $('#email').val() ? false : true
           },   
                email: {
                    required: $('#mobile').val() ? false : true
                }
       },

    });
```

Works fine:

```
var form = $( "#send_request_sms" );
    form.validate({
       rules: {
           first_name: { 
             required: true 
           } , 
               last_name: { 
               required: true 
           },              
                        mobile: { 
               required: true
           },   
                email: {
                    required: true
                }
       },

    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "does not work"? What is happening and what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 2):

I generally use `depends` and works in my case

```
var form = $( "#send_request_sms" );
form.validate({
   rules: {
       first_name: { 
         required: true 
       } , 
       last_name: { 
           required: true 
       },              
        mobile: { 
           required: {depends: function(element) {
                         return jQuery("#email").val() == '' ? true : false;
                        }
                     }
              },   
            email: {
                required: {depends: function(element) {
                        return jQuery("#mobile").val() == '' ? true : false;
                        }
                     }
            }
   }

});
```

Comment: Yup, this seems to be the appropriate way to do this, as per the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate). The reason the way the OP was doing it originally didn't work is because the conditionals were only getting evaluated on the first call to `.validate()`, right when the page loaded. Both fields are blank when the page loads, so both conditionals always evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving the conditional statement outside the validate object.

e.g.

```
var form = $("#send_request_sms");
var mobileRequired = $('#email').val() ? false : true;
var emailedRequired = $('#mobile').val() ? false : true;
form.validate({
   rules: {
       first_name: { 
         required: true 
       }, 
       last_name: { 
         required: true 
       },              
       mobile: { 
         required: mobileRequired
       },   
       email: {
         required: emailRequired
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Need to switch those up. OP wants email required if mobile has no value, and mobile required if email has no value.

Comment: Good catch! Updating. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the order of email and mobile

```
var form = $( "#send_request_sms" );
form.validate({
   rules: {
       first_name: { 
         required: true 
       } , 
       last_name: { 
           required: true 
       },              
       mobile: { 
           required: $('#mobile').val() ? false : true
       },   
       email: {
           required: $('#email').val() ? false : true
       }
   },

});
```

Comment: No, OP's trying to make it so that either mobile or email is required. So if mobile has no value, then email is required and if email has no value, then mobile is required.

Comment: Yes it makes more sense the way you have said it, but even then he will get a false against mobile even when it is entered.

Comment: exactly. thanks for clarifying that for me. So I tried James option and validation is still wrong.

Comment: James, I tried your updated code and it still requires email when the phone number has been entered